# Performing realtime Google Cloud speech recognition with PyAudio + VB-Audio virtual cable

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual, pyaudio, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to perform streaming speech recognition with the realtime Google Cloud Speech API. I have used the second code snippet from here (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-streaming-audio) to successfully transcribe audio from the microphone.

I want to perform the same, but using audio coming from a different source, such as an Internet socket. For this, I have used VB-Cable and PyAudio in order to simulate input coming from the microphone: I take the input from the socket and forward it to a virtual device acting as a microphone. The main parts of the Python code are below:

```
# ----- client.py -----
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 30000))

wf = wave.open('test.wav', 'rb')
rate = wf.getframerate()
data = wf.readframes(48000)

while data != b'':
    bytes_sent = s.send(data)
    print('Sent {} bytes'.format(bytes_sent))
    data = wf.readframes(48000)


# ----- server.py -----
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', 30000))
s.listen()

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Got connection from {}'.format(addr))

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                    channels=1,
                    rate=48000,
                    output=True,
                    output_device_index=3) # VB-Cable output device ID

    while True:
        data = c.recv(48000)
        print('Received {} bytes'.format(len(data)))
        if data == b'':
            break
        stream.write(data)


# ----- mic-simulator.py -----
client, streaming_config = setup_microphone() # performs streaming config initialization, same as the first few lines in `main()`, in the link to Google Cloud Speech example

while True:
    with MicrophoneStream(48000, 4800) as stream:
        audio_generator = stream.generator()
        requests_ = (
            speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                for content in audio_generator
        )

        responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests_)

        # Now, put the transcription responses to use.
        listen_print_loop(responses) # same as the function in the link to the Google Cloud Speech example
```

The problem with the code above is that sometimes I get the transcription results from Google Cloud Speech, but sometimes not. I have checked the VB-audio virtual cable parameters and whenever I forward the data coming from the socket, the input interface actually gets the data. Is it possible that the problem is some kind of rate-limiting imposed by Google Cloud speech? Anyone has a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices-provide-speech-data) by Google help you to solve your problem? Let me know whether this is helpful or not.

Comment: @kiranmathew I checked it, but the linked information did not help much. What helped however is this GitHub example - https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/main/samples/microphone/transcribe_streaming_infinite.py

Comment: The above example seems to continuously check whether the submitted request is taking too long to respond. In this case, the request is re-submitted and the responses arive on time now

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer for the above issue?

Comment: @kiranmathew I suspect that the Streaming speech recognition API from Google is not well supported for languages other than 'en-US'. But I am still looking for a confirmation to this. Or maybe a different reason for not working.